# Redux - keep or clean data received from API in state?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I use redux in all my lms application built with react and redux and normally save the data received from the API backend in the redux store.
My question is: can I keep all the data received in the store or is it better to delete them every time I change the page?

To give a practical example: a part of my application receives a list of courses and I save this list in the store. Then I click on a course, get the list of lessons and save it in the store. Then I click a lesson, get the videos and additional information about the lesson, and save it to the store.
Should I keep all these data in the store or (even if I am not sure how) should I ensure that they are deleted every time the related component / page is no longer visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it all.  That way you can avoid re-doing the same API queries when the user goes back and forth between pages.

You'll want to [normalize your state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) so that you can look up a lesson, video, course, etc. by its id or slug.  When you are on a page for `/lesson/455` you would select the lesson #455 from the store rather than looking at some sort of "current lesson" property.